# Where are the username and passwords stored in the default ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a project using Visual Studio 2012  "ASP.NET Web Forms Application" (Not the blank one). I have registered a few users with the apps register form. I was wondering where in my project is the username and password stored for the logins?

Comment: What does your `web.config` say?

Comment: @Dai I didn't know it was stored there. Thanks is this what I am looking for? <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ChoresLists-20131219095601;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ChoresLists-20131219095601.mdf" />

Comment: So, that would be the answer. They are stored in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in a database, most likely in your local sql express. The passwords are hashed of course.

Answer (score 3):

Check webconfig connection string
by default it uses localdb sql express
In solution explorer click on show all files
and inside appdata u will find the database file